# Changing the style of Individual cells in a datagridview row

Tags: vb.net, datagrid, datagridview, windows-forms-designer

Is it possible to give individual cells in a data grid view row different styles such as backcolor, fontcolor etc?

I do not mean giving the whole row a new style, only a specific cell.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

certainly:

`Me.myDatagridview.Rows(0).Cells(0).Style.ForeColor = Color.Aqua`

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
  if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
  {
      string imageName = e.Row.Cells[0].Text.ToString();
      e.Row.Cells[1].Attributes.Add(“Style”,
        “background-image: url(’images/” + imageName + “‘);”);    
  }
}
```

Comment: post is tagged as windows forms, vb.net